# Why do my Spark executors run out of memory overhead?

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, hadoop-yarn

I have a simple ETL job written in Spark/Scala that basically does this:

```scala
val queriesPar = queries.par
queriesPar.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(numExecutors, ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, true))
queriesPar.foreach { query =>
     spark
         .read
         .format("jdbc")
         .option("...") //user, password, driver, fetch size, etc.
         .option("query", query.sql)
         .load()
         .withColumn("partition_name", query.partName)
         .write
         .mode("append")
         .format("hive")
         .partitionBy("partition_name")
         .saveAsTable(hiveTable)
}
```

Each query is guaranteed to read less than 3 GB of data from the JDBC source. From time to time my executors are killed by YARN with `Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 4.5 GB of 4 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.`

I've dutifully boosted the memory overhead to 3 GB, with the other 5 GB of the memory being assigned to the executor. And yet some executors still fail to process specific tasks while others retry and succeed.

Spark is correct when it suggests I increase memory overhead, because it's YARN that's killing my containers, not JVM via `-Xmx` and `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError`. And yet I have no idea what goes into there. Spark documentation says, "This is memory that accounts for things like VM overheads, interned strings, other native overheads, etc.". At first I thought, "okay, maybe the native part of the JDBC driver needs this memory for fetching the data", but then I realized it's 100% managed, so there's no native overhead.

What goes into that mysterious memory overhead?

Why do some executors succeed when others fail at the same task?

Comment: it could be that each/some partitions are too big to be processed in the executor memory, try to repartition after load `.load().repartition(N)` and iterate on the number based on your cluster resources. This can make each partition smaller and easier to process

Comment: I shrunk my executor memory to 1GB and expanded the overhead to 5GB and the errors went away, so the overhead was the culprit. I just have no idea how to estimate or control what goes into the overhead.